# How to create a customer managed customer master key (CMK) i AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-kms

When creating a  a key-signing key (KSK) in Route 53 a customer managed customer master key (CMK) needs to be created ( [Working with customer managed CMKs for DNSSEC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-configuring-dnssec-cmk-requirements.html) )

> The customer managed CMK must be an asymmetric CMK with an
> ECC_NIST_P256 key spec.

When trying to create CMK, I get "KeySpec ECC_NIST_P256 is not supported"

```sh
aws kms create-key --region us-east-1 --origin EXTERNAL --customer-master-key-spec ECC_NIST_P256
 --key-usage SIGN_VERIFY


An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateKey operation: KeySpec ECC_NIST_P256 is not supported for Origin EXTERNAL
```

How could you create the CMK key in order to create KSK?

Answer (score 0):

KMS [does not support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/importing-keys.html) importing asymmetric CMKs:

> Imported key material is **supported only for symmetric CMKs** in AWS KMS key stores. It is not supported on asymmetric CMKs or CMKs in custom key stores.

You have to use AWS provided key material through `--origin AWS_KMS`. Maybe you could also use `AWS_CLOUDHSM`, but this can be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

```
Name space need to add from nuget packeg

using Amazon.KeyManagementService;
using Amazon.KeyManagementService.Model; 

**1) Encryption :-**
AmazonKeyManagementServiceConfig kmsConfig = new AmazonKeyManagementServiceConfig();
            kmsConfig.UseHttp = true;
            kmsConfig.ServiceURL = serviceEndPoint;           
                //create client, specify Region end point or kms config
                AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient kmsClient = new AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient(awsKeyForKMS, awsSecretKeyForKMS, kmsConfig);
                GenerateDataKeyRequest dataKeyReq = new GenerateDataKeyRequest();
                dataKeyReq.KeyId = keyARNForKMS;
                dataKeyReq.KeySpec = DataKeySpec.AES_256;//The length of the data encryption key. AES_256 to generate a 256-bit symmetric key.
                GenerateDataKeyResponse dataKeyResponse = kmsClient.GenerateDataKey(dataKeyReq);
                //read encrypted data key from memory
                MemoryStream streamCipherText = dataKeyResponse.CiphertextBlob;
               // need to save this key with encrypted data because with the help of it 
               // you can decrypt(you got plaindatakey) the data
                encryptedDataKey = Convert.ToBase64String(streamCipherText.ToArray());

                //read plain data key from memory
                MemoryStream streamPlainText = dataKeyResponse.Plaintext;
              // use this key to encrypt your data and than forgot this key
                plainDataKey = Convert.ToBase64String(streamPlainText.ToArray());    
               //your encryption logic
                Encryption encrypt = new Encryption();
                encrypt.EncryptTextForKms(PlainKey, "data to be encrypted")
```